# Populate ListView after Button Click in Fragments

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-button, android-listfragment

So I'm trying populate a ListView in one Fragment after adding Text in an EditText field after a button click in another Fragment.

My java coding skills are pretty bad, so any code suggestions would help me a lot.

I hope this makes sense.

Here's my code.

```
public class FieldsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final int NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 3;
ViewPager mPager;
MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter;
ArrayList<String>siteList = new ArrayList<String>();
CustomAdapter ca = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.fields);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.topbar);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fieldspager);
    mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

Where my ListView is.

```
public  class AddSite extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_site, container, false);
        Button addSiteButton = (Button) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSiteButton);
        addSiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 mPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
             }
        });

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ca);
        return mRelativeLayout;
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        CustomAdapter() {
            super(FieldsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, siteList);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            }
           ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textViewId)).setText(siteList.get(position));
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

Where the Button and EditText is.

```
public class CreateSite extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        final EditText siteEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.siteEditText);
        Button signInButton = (Button) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {    //Click this button and add to ListView in class AddSite
                siteList.add(0, siteEditText.getText().toString());
                ca.notifyDataSetChanged(); //(Bundle) cannot be applied
                siteEditText.setText("");
                mPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            }
        });
        return mRelativeLayout;
    }
}
```

While all in a FragmentPagerAdapter

```
private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
         switch (position) {
            case 0: return new SettingFields();
            case 1: return new AddSite();
            case 2: return new CreateSite();
        }
       return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
    }
}

}
```

So I've commented the errors that are shown.

Hope this makes sense.
Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your fragments should not talk directly to each other.  Instead, each fragment should report the Activity, and the Activity can decide what to do with that action.

The normal way to do this is to have a Fragment define an interface, and have the Activity implement that interface.  Then there is a method  that the Fragment can call, on the Activity.  Then the Activity can call a method on the other Fragment to make it perform some action.

See the documentation on [Fragment communication](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: how would I change my code to fit those requirements or is the way I wrote this just flat out wrong? In other words is this fixable or do I need to start over?